# adjacency matrix from text file c code

Tags: c, file, matrix, file-handling, adjacency-matrix

For a project, I need to take an adjacency matrix as input in a C program from a text file. The text file contains the edge details of the graph for which the matrix is to be constructed. The format of the text file is given below.

```
   5    4
   3    2
   0    1
   1    0
   4    5
```

Each line contains an edge, shown by tab-separated values. For example, in the first line, there is an edge from node 5 to node 4.
I need to take input from this file and show the matrix as output in C.
Can anyone please help me how to proceed?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Is that just random data? Two pairs are duplicated in reverse order.

Comment: @WeatherVane That depends upon what type of graph it is .

Comment: @ameyCU whatever it is, is discontinuous.

Comment: @WeatherVane it is a sample graph of interactions in a network i.e each edge represents an interaction between the nodes. the graph is therefore directed

Answer (score 2):

1. Open file in read mode.
2. Declare an 2-D array namely `adj[][]`(size according to question be `adj[6][6]`).
3. Initialize all elements of array to `0`.
4. Read file and store value it into two variables `n` and `m` (using for example the `fscanf()` function).
5. Update value in `adj[][]` to `1` corresponding to index `n and m`.

(Steps 4 and 5 inside a loop to read file until EOF)

6. Then close file.

Comment: I am relatively new to file handling. So I cant figure out how to read the tab-separated values into variables in each line. I mean, which function do I have to use?

Comment: Look into `fscanf` in `stdio.h`. It lets you specify a format of expected data to read from a file, and the variables to read the data into.

Comment: @amun101 You can learn about `fscanf` from here -http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm

Comment: for ( x = 0;x < v;x++ )
        {
            for ( y = 0;y < v;y++ )
                adj[x][y]=0;

        }

    while(!eof(fp))
    {

                  fscanf(fp, " %d %d ", &origin, &destin);
                  adj[origin][destin]=1;

    }




        fclose(fp);


    for ( x = 0;x < v;x++ )
        {
            for ( y = 0;y < v;y++ )
                printf("%d", adj[x][y]);
          printf("\n");
        }

Comment: this is what i have done after steps 1 & 2. is this correct? @Laogeodritt

Comment: okay it is solved now. i had given eof instead of feof, so it was not working. it's working fine now. thanks

Comment: @ EOF I just meant  here as end of file . Well you resolved it by feof nice work .